# this.state.todos.map is not a function, React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, jsx

I'm making a simple Todo list which consists of a container `App` component as well as a child `Todo` stateless functional component.  When I create a new todo, I expect it to be added to the todos array that I have defined in the parent components state.  However, when I do so, I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: this.state.todos.map is not a function`.  Can someone please help me understand why this is.

Here is the parent component:

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
    input: '',
    todos: [
     'buy milk',
     'buy eggs',
     'take out trash'
    ]
   };
   this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
   this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(e){
   let value = this.state.input;
   let todos = this.state.todos;
   let newTodos = todos.push(value);
   this.setState({todos: newTodos, input: ''});

  }

  handleChange(e){
   this.setState({input: e.target.value})
  }


  render() {
   let todolist = this.state.todos.map((value, index) => {
    return(
     <ul>
      <Todo value={value} />
     </ul>
    )
   })
    return (
      <div>
      <h1>My Todo list</h1>
       <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input 
         type='text'
         onChange={this.handleChange} 
         value={this.state.input}
         />
        <input type='submit'/>
       </form>
      {todolist}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the child component:

```js
let Todo = (props) => {
 return(
  <li>{props.value}</li>
 )
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `let newTodos = todos.push(value);` will be the length of the array, i.e. `3`. When you update your `todos` in the state to this you will get your error.

You need to prevent the default behavior of the `form` (which is to reload the browser) with `preventDefault`, and you can add the todo like this instead to avoid mutation of the `todos` array:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  this.setState(previousState => {
    return {
      todos: [...previousState.todos, previousState.input],
      input: ""
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: Combined with `e.preventDefault()`, this works, thanks!

Comment: @MiddleZ Ah, I missed that it was part of the form. I updated the answer. You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Just to add an improvement. Currently you have this:

```
let todolist = this.state.todos.map((value, index) => {
  return (<ul>
    <Todo value={value}/>
  </ul>)
})
```

It will render a UL for each todo, and your HTML will look like:

```
<ul><li>buy milk</li></ul>
<ul><li>buy eggs</li></ul>
<ul><li>take out trash</li></ul>
```

You can do this:

```
render() {
  let todolist = this.state.todos.map((value, index) => {
  return <Todo value={value}/> // Return only the todo, not the UL
})
return (<div>
  <h1>My Todo list</h1>
  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <input type='text' onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.input}/>
    <input type='submit'/>
  </form>
  <ul>{todolist}</ul> // UL here

</div>);}
}
```

And you will render a single UL:

```
<ul>
  <li>buy milk</li>
  <li>buy eggs</li>
  <li>take out trash</li>
</ul>
```